# Exchange 2010: How to add a room calendar to a user's OWA?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

We've added serveral users as delegates to rooms. They are able to manage the room calendars fine. However, it does not appear in their OWA "My calendars" list.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Is there something we could do server-side? Or instructions we could give users to perform this in OWA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click Share>Add Calendar on the toolbar part of the calendar view in OWA.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Calendar. Right click on "My Calendars" and go down to "Add Calendar...". From there you may add other user's calendars or room calendars.

I'm doing this on Exchange 2010 SP1...I'm not sure if this is a feature added to SP1 as OWA changed a bit between service packs.